# how to compare update_option() after it saves to database?

Tags: options

i am having trouble getting any usable information or example of the update_option action hook. my aim is to compare both old and new value of my data, then send email to user for changes. below is the hook:

```
add_action('update_option', function( $option_name, $old_value, $value ) {
 //....
}, 10, 3)
```

i have compied the code as is to test run but nothing happened. my question is what goes into $option_name, $old_value, $value? sorry am fairly new to php. any explanation with any example will be appreciated.

EDIT:

below is the full code. the idea is to compare the data if it has changed, then echo:

```
 add_action('updated_option', function( $options, $old_value, $value ) {
 $options = $options;
foreach ($options as $value) {
    $value['id'] = $old_value;
    $value['id'] = $value;
}
if($old_value == $value){
    echo 'data is current';
else{
    echo 'there has been changes';
  }
}, 10, 3);
```

i still don't get anything.

Comment: Well, if that `//....` is just like that in your actual code, then nothing would happen. And the parameters are: `$option_name` - the option name; `$old_value` - the old option value; `$value` - the new option value. See [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/update_option/).

Comment: @SallyCJ. appreciate the response. i have posted the full code. any idea on what i may be doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry about the previous comments... that I've deleted. And the main problem in your code is that the `$options` is the option name and not the option value. If you just want to see if the option has been changed, then `add_action( 'update_option_{your_option_name}', function(){ echo 'Option changed'; } );` would do it because if there were no changes, WordPress won't trigger the `update_option_your_option_name` or `updated_option` hook.

Comment: @SallyCJ thanks for reply. my option name contains userID. and although your explanation is straight foward, i only want to check for one option change. my code: `add_action( 'update_option_{'.$userID.'_interview_date}', function(){ 
 echo 'Option changed'; 
 } 
);`. i did that and nothing happened. if there's another way to achieve this i will be grateful.

Comment: You shouldn't include the brackets (`{` and `}`).. but anyway, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the full code in the updated question, it seems that you're just checking if the option has been changed; so for that purpose, you could simply do so, where `<option name>` is the option name like `my_option`:

```php
add_action( 'update_option_<option name>', function(){
    // you shouldn't echo, but this is just for testing
    echo 'option changed';
} );
```

***And if the option's value is actually the same as the old one, the above function won't be called.*** Because that's how `update_option()` works — if it's called but no changes in the option's value, then the hook `update_option_<option name>` won't be called. And neither does the `updated_option` or `update_option` hook.

Now you said, "*my option name contains user ID*" and mentioned that the option name is `<user ID>_interview_date`. And in that case, you can do something like this:

- Option 1: Validates the user ID/data:

  ```php
  add_action( 'updated_option', function( $option_name ){
      if ( preg_match( '/^(\d+)_interview_date$/', $option_name, $matches ) ) {
          $user_id = absint( $matches[1] );
          // Check if the user exists.
          if ( $user_id && ( $user = get_userdata( $user_id ) ) ) {
              // you shouldn't echo, but this is just for testing
              echo $option_name . ' option changed';
          }
      }
  } );
  ```
- Option 2: No validations..

  ```php
  add_action( 'updated_option', function( $option_name ){
      if ( preg_match( '/^(\d+)_interview_date$/', $option_name, $matches ) ) {
          // you shouldn't echo, but this is just for testing
          echo $option_name . ' option changed; no validations performed..';
      }
  } );
  ```

Comment: spot on. Checkmarked for perfect example.